# Is php-gtk still alive?

Tags: php, gtk

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and PHP 7.4.3 .
I want to try using php-gtk, but I am finding it very confusing.

- Is the project still alive?
- What are the prerequisites - can they really mean PHP-5.1 or 5.2 (EOL 6 Jan 2011)?
- Does "or later" include PHP 7.4?

I have downloaded and unzipped the sources into /php-gtk-src-master. It contains a buildconf script, but this fails with "no phpize". Somehow I installed phpize, but then buildconf says:

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'configure.in', needed by 'aclocal.m4'.  Stop.  
make: *** [build2/build.mk:12: all] Error 2
```

I have used wxPHP, but this died after PHP 5.6.  It was restarted with PHP_7 last year, but the developer disappeared without doing any documentation, and is effectively dead again.

I have looked at QT 5.15, but my request for support died after a few emails.

I need a script to follow that works starting from a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04 .

Answer (score 1):

The php-gtk [seems](https://github.com/php/php-gtk-src) [to be](https://repology.org/projects/?search=php+gtk&maintainer=&category=&inrepo=&notinrepo=&repos=&families=&repos_newest=&families_newest=) [dead](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=php%20gtk).

But you can try to use modern one, it is called `php-gtk3`. You have to consult with the [documentation from GitHub repo](https://github.com/scorninpc/php-gtk3).

Comment: Thanks for that.
I have got further with php-gtk3, but still can't complete the build of the package.
php-gtk should be remove from github.

Answer (score 1):

I had got exactly the same error trying to run `buildconf --with-phpize=/opt/php74/bin/phpize` in `php-gtk-src-master` folder.

Separately, I have **XAMPP for Linux 7.1.26** - installed in default directory `/opt/lampp`.

Hence when I run the `phpize` command from the `xampp`
(`buildconf --with-phpize=/opt/lampp/bin/phpize`), it generates all files without any error. Make sure `autoconf` is installed already.

Try and check with `php-version 7.1.26`

**OS: fedora33**